# Why so slow Android service restarting with START_STICKY?

Tags: android, android-service, background-service

I have a background service, and I am doing all the operations on this service.
The service is working with activities at times. But if the application closes, the service restart with `START_STICKY`; It works correctly, but sometimes it takes a long time to restart, like more than a minute.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    SocketIOConnect();
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {      
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

How do I reduce the restart time?

Comment: most likely SocketIOConnect(); takes that long

Comment: I tried without this function.I tried empty service.But same result.:/

Answer (score 3):

> How do I reduce restart time?

You do not control this. It is up to the OS to determine when it will restart services whose processes were terminated for one reason or another.

Bear in mind that your service might *never* restart, if the user force-stopped your app (e.g., from Settings).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot control that. But however, I could suggest some good practices.

- You should call the `super.onCreate();` first before calling other methods inside your `overrided` method.
- If your `service class` is `extended` from `IntentService class`, and if you decide to also `override` other callback methods, such as `onCreate()`, `onStartCommand()`, or `onDestroy()`, be sure to call the `super` implementation, so that the `IntentService` can properly handle the life of the worker thread. [check from android developer side](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

You can call the `super.onStartCommand()` as follows:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, START_STICKY, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

- The constant variable `START_STICKY` will let the service run indefinitely until you explicitly call `stopService()` or `stopSelf()`. Therefore, make sure that you have the option to stop it, otherwise you have to force stop it from *Application Settings*.
- You can add a category TAG to your service before starting so then you can use that TAG to **uniquely** identify and stop the service externally by calling `stopService()` method.

**Starting service**

```
serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
                serviceIntent.addCategory(MYTAG);
                startService(serviceIntent);
```

**Stopping service**

```
serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
                    serviceIntent.addCategory(MYTAG);
                    stopService(serviceIntent);
```