# How to restart android service if killed

Tags: android, service

I have created a service which runs in background and send GPSlocation server after every 30 seconds 
but after few hours the service stops working
how to prevent that or restart the service if OS killed the service

Comment: start a sticky service if it gets killed system will restart it

Comment: I have already added it but i think it is taking too long to start service is there anyway to start immediately after OS kills app

Answer (score 1):

Change onStartCommand() method as follows.

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

   //Your code

   return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: I have already added it but i think it is taking too long to start service 
is there anyway to start immediately after OS kills app

Comment: It is not possible as per this answer : -https://stackoverflow.com/a/25569550/2470816